# TeamCity takes over 7 minutes in Nuget Installer

Tags: teamcity

We use an internal Nuget server in TeamCity for nuget packages. Off late we are seeing that the **Nuget Installer** step is taking very long to complete. We don't know why. We are on 7.1.5. Here is the log file from the step (note it takes **7m:12s**). There are 16 `packages.config` file in the entire solution.

```html
[12:29:59]Skip checking for changes - changes are already collected
[12:29:59]Publishing internal artifacts
[12:29:59]Clearing temporary directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp
[12:29:59]Clean build enabled: removing old files from C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\XXXXXXX\CmplPkgContent
[12:29:59]Checkout directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\XXXXXXX\CmplPkgContent
[12:29:59]Updating sources: server side checkout (52s)
[12:30:51]Resolving artifact dependencies (2s)
[12:30:53]Step 1/16: CreateArtifactDir (MSBuild) (24s)
[12:31:18]Step 2/16: Increment Platform (Command Line) (15s)
[12:31:34]Step 3/16: Increment XXXXXXX (Command Line) (1s)
[12:31:35]Step 4/16: Copy Platform (Command Line) (5s)
[12:31:41]Step 5/16: NugetUpdate_XXXXXXX (NuGet Installer) (2m:30s)
[12:34:11]Step 6/16: NugetUpdate (NuGet Installer) (7m:12s)
[12:41:24]Step 7/16: NugetUpdate_IntegrationTests (NuGet Installer) (1m:12s)
[12:42:36]Step 8/16: Compile XXXXXXX (Visual Studio (sln))
[12:42:36]Step 9/16: Compile Integration Tests (Visual Studio (sln)) (3s)
[12:42:40]Step 10/16: CompileXXXXXXX (Visual Studio (sln)) (3m:35s)
[12:46:16]Step 11/16: Copy Packaging (MSBuild) (23s)
[12:46:40]Step 12/16: CopyForgeModules (MSBuild) (18s)
[12:46:58]Step 13/16: Signing (MSBuild) (1m:21s)
[12:48:20]Step 14/16: XXXXXXX CreateInstall (MSBuild) (50s)
[12:49:11]Step 15/16: XXXXXXX CreateUpgrade (MSBuild) (38s)
[12:49:50]Step 16/16: XXXXXXX CreateSymbols (MSBuild) (29s)
[12:50:20]Publishing artifacts
[12:50:20]Publishing artifacts
[12:50:20]Publishing artifacts
[12:50:20]Publishing internal artifacts
[12:50:20]Publishing artifacts (20s)
[12:50:41]Build finished
```

Comment: I have the same problem started 10 Feb 2015. Each NuGet packages installation takes exactly one minute. See my TeamCity log https://gist.github.com/dizel3d/1b3dcf45f430b8f583c6

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. See my correspondence with NuGet support:

> My team uses TeamCity build server which downloads NuGet packages for
>   each build task. Since 10 Feb 2015 we noticed "NuGet.exe install"
>   delays for 1 minute before run. This our TeamCity log
>   https://gist.github.com/dizel3d/1b3dcf45f430b8f583c6. Have you applied
>   limitation for us? If it's true, we will use local NuGet mirror.

I got the answer:

> The issue is not readily apparent to us.  The 1-minute delay seems to
>   be between the time you invoke NuGet.exe and the time it starts the
>   actual restore where the server is involved.   Could you share the
>   packages.config file with us so that we can try to reproduce the same
>   invocation?   I’m also wondering about NuGet.exe’s processing of
>   NuGet.Config files.  It will walk your directories to find config
>   files.  The following folders will be inspected:
>
> 1. %ProgramData%\NuGet
> 2. %AppData%\NuGet
> 3. The root of the drive the packages.config file is in
> 4. Every folder between the root of the drive and the folder where the packages.config file is
>
> Is any of those by chance on a slow volume or network share?  Could
>   you use DiskMon to check to see what all nuget.exe is checking and see
>   if any of those is having issues?

I said:

> We use .NET SDK of special cryptographic software. 10 Feb 2015 the
>   software license was expired. And the software has been showing a
>   warning window for 1 minute before each "NuGet.exe install" execution.
>   We have already solved the problem.

For resolving my issue I executed slow NuGet.exe command on TeamCity worker server:

```
"C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2\work\550c756e62fcf12f.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2\work\550c756e62fcf12f\src\OTC.CodingSchemes\packages.config" -source "" -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent2\work\550c756e62fcf12f\ "
```

And saw the damn warning window required to enter new licence key during one minute :-)

Answer (score 0):

What I noted is that TeamCity spends over 1 minute trying to authenticate itself with it's own internal nuget server. Here is the relevant portion from the build log:

```
[13:24:42][update] Looking for updates for 'WebFormsMvp'...
[13:24:43][update] Using credentials from config. UserName: xxx
[13:25:51][update] Applying constraint 'WebFormsMvp (= 1.4.1.0)' defined in packages.config.
```

As can be seen - it takes 68 seconds between line 2 and 3.

Since we use internal nuget packages, we were able to combine several DLLs into one giant nuget package to reduce the lookups.